# JS: Radio buttons - dynamically generated based on selection

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

I have a problem how to describe that, hope you get what I want to say:

Let's say: what are your top two car brands:

I chose #1 from:
**Audi, VW, BWM, Jaguar**  (it's BWM)

For #2 the options should be same without BMW:
**Audi, VW, Jaguar**

How can I deduct choice #1 from the 2nd options field?

Any hint is appreciated!

(I usually write PHP, but I like to achieve that without screen reload, I know JS can probably do that, but I lack that skill)

Comment: Do you have that 2 options initially, or you want to generate second "fieldset" automatically? Can you share sample html (And javascript if you have something?)

Comment: And, do you use any library like jQuery?

Comment: So far I have nothing. Basically both form_sets are the same, except for #2 is minus the option that chosen in form #1. My plan is to use it inside Wordpress, I guess I can use JQuery too. (PS, I can write it in PHP, but I prefer to avoid the page reload.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is using jQuery library and it works in a following way:

If you choose something from fieldset 1 it just hide's similar input from another fieldset.

Also it hides label that is located near input tag.

You can run this snippet to find how it works.

```js
$("input[name=cars_0]").change(function(){

  
  var val = $(this).val();
  

 // Show everything before hiding new one
  $("input[name=cars_1]").show()
   .prev('label').show();
  
  // Hide input tag based on value
   $("input[name=cars_1][value="+val+"]").hide()
   .prev('label').hide(); //Hide label tag
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <fieldset>
    <label for="audi_0">Audi</label>
    <input id="audi_0" type="radio" name="cars_0" value="audi">

    <label for="bmw_0">BMW</label>
    <input id="bmw_0" type="radio" name="cars_0" value="bmw">
    
    <label for="jaguar_0">Jaguar</label>
    <input id="jaguar_0" type="radio" name="cars_0" value="jaguar">
    
  </fieldset>
  
  <fieldset>
    <label for="audi_1">Audi</label>
    <input id="audi_1" type="radio" name="cars_1" value="audi">

    <label for="bmw_1">BMW</label>
    <input id="bmw_1" type="radio" name="cars_1" value="bmw">
    
    <label for="jaguar_1">Jaguar</label>
    <input id="jaguar_1" type="radio" name="cars_1" value="jaguar">
    
  </fieldset>
  
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's very close to what I need. Only: Option #1 need to stay, because after "SUBMIT" I need both options to send to MySQL

Comment: Oops, i just have same names for both. updating

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!